# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2) with URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: swift, macos, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to get to the bottom of a problem with happens infrequently and unpredictably.

I have the following code:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestURL) { data, response, error in
```

(which then goes on to handle the response)

Periodically it will crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2) and, despite all my reading about this, I can't seem to figure out what is causing this and how to avoid it. Articles that I've read say it's a "programmer error" but what that error is, isn't made clear.

This is on macOS 10.15 in Xcode 11.1.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Please, show all of your code in this method, not only first line.

Comment: @hocker have you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: I haven't. Project has been on the shelf as a result.